# Not able to read the system variable set from GebConfig.groovy file in spec file

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I am using geb spock. I am trying to read the system variable from GebConfig file, however it returns the null value.

Below is my GebConfig.groovy file.

```
def final DEFAULT_BROWSER = "chrome"   
def final DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "nl"                  //"en" or "nl"

def browser = System.getProperty("geb.env")
//Default browser
if (!correctBrowser(browser)) {
    browser = DEFAULT_BROWSER
}

def envLang = System.getProperty("geb.env.lang")
//Default language
if (!correctLanguage(envLang)) {
    envLang = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
}

System.setProperty("geb.env.lang", envLang)

System.setProperty("geb.env", browser)

environments {
    driver = { getDriver(browser, envLang) }
}
```

Below is my spec file where I am trying to get the language value in a variable.

```
@Stepwise
class TC001_SMO_Scenario_Spec extends GebReportingSpec {


    @Shared
    def lang = System.getProperty("geb.env.lang")


    def "Step 1: Perform Login"() {

        when: "Load File"
        to WUPage

        then: " File loaded successfully"
        println " Getting data from Geb Config File: " + lang

    }

}
```

Can you please help me how to do this, as this is very important for me to access and store it in a variable. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why, but all my GebConfigs call getProperty in the setProperty: System.setProperty("geb.env.lang", System.getProperty("geb.env.lang", envLang))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `@Shared` variable. The [Geb manual](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_fields) says:

> (...) declare a @Shared field. Again it’s best to initialize the field right at the point of declaration. (Semantically, this is equivalent to initializing the field at the very beginning of the `setupSpec()` method.)

The thing is, `setupSpec()` runs **before** `GebConfig` is evaluated. You can see it if you add this to the end of your `GebConfig`:

```java
println "Finished evaluating GebConfig"
```

Then run this Geb specification (I have wrapped the variable assignments into closures and added print statements, then I am evaluating the closures so as to make the assignments work):

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import spock.lang.Shared

class GebConfigIT extends GebReportingSpec {
  @Shared
  def sharedLang = {
    println "Initialising sharedLang"
    System.getProperty("geb.env.lang")
  }()

  def normalLang = {
    println "Initialising normalLang"
    System.getProperty("geb.env.lang")
  }()

  def setup() {
    println "sharedLang = $sharedLang"
    println "normalLang = $normalLang"
  }

  def foo() {
    expect:
    !sharedLang
    normalLang
  }

  def bar() {
    expect:
    !sharedLang
    normalLang
  }
}
```

```
Initialising sharedLang

Finished evaluating GebConfig
Initialising normalLang
sharedLang = null
normalLang = nl

Initialising normalLang
Finished evaluating GebConfig
sharedLang = null
normalLang = nl
```

Can you see how `sharedLang` is initialised only once at the very beginning, before `GebConfig` even gets a chance to kick in?

Bottom line: Just remove `@Shared` from your code. It is over-used by most people anyway, they think they save time this way for cheap resources and tamper with their clean fixture setups. `@Shared` really is only for very expensive resources and very exceptional cases.

Comment: While your answer is correct in that it will fix the OP's problem and set the variable to the system property set in `GebConfig.groovy` I'd argue that setting system properties in it is a bad idea. You then end up having to read the system property only after `GebConfig.groovy` has been evaluated and the time at which it happens is an implemenation detail of `GebSpec` and `Browser` in my opinion. It's hard to understand what the OP is trying to do with the language value so it's not easy to suggest a better solution.

Comment: No objections to your opinion about this not being such a good idea. I just wanted to answer the question. Whatever he wants to do with the language information (probably he also could have gotten it from the browser instance somehow, I did not check), it could be potentially useful. And after all, the lifecycle info I quoted from the Book of Geb explains quite well why the information is available for normal instance members, but not for shared ones. So it seems safe to use it.

Comment: Thanks kriegaex and erdi.
When I removed @Shared tag, found it working. 
I am planning to get the language name on run time and concatenate the string based on  the name of my test data property file. That's the reason I wanted to read it from GebConfig file.
Thanks for your help on this